# Toggle multiline or single line in parenthesis Vim

Tags: python, vim

When coding Python I usually find myself wanting to break lines containing long lists or functions containing several arguments into multiple lines.

Between this:

```py
# Example 1
foo(this_is_a_long_variable_1, this_is_a_long_variable_2, this_is_a_long_variable_3, this_is_a_long_variable_4)

# Example 2
def bar():
    return [this_is_a_long_variable_1, this_is_a_long_variable_2, this_is_a_long_variable_3, this_is_a_long_variable_4]
```

and this:

```py
# Example 1
foo(
    this_is_a_long_variable_1,
    this_is_a_long_variable_2,
    this_is_a_long_variable_3,
    this_is_a_long_variable_4,
)

# Example 2
def bar():
    return [
        this_is_a_long_variable_1,
        this_is_a_long_variable_2,
        this_is_a_long_variable_3,
        this_is_a_long_variable_4,
    ]
```

What is the best way to do this?

From what I can gather I want to connect a special action to [object-select](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select) and the actions themselves should be relatively okay to do by regex replace with some special handling of adding an extra comma before the end of the block.

But I have never really done anything this advanced before with Vim and don't really know where to start.

Comment: Have you considered using a formatter? e.g here https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#how-black-wraps-lines and to install `pip install black` then just run it against your file you can also setup black to run upon save if you want. Or just invoke it on demand via `black file.py`

Comment: Yes, that is something I've considered. However, I'd like to be able to toggle between single line and multi-line directly in vim as I find editing with respect to lines is usually easier than editing based on words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, the low-level pieces…

1. Change the content of the parentheses to this:

   ```
   foo(
   )
   ```

   with:

   ```
   ci(<CR><Esc>
   ```

   leaving the cursor on `)`.
2. Put the result of the following expression on the line above the cursor:

   ```
   :put!=getreg('\"')->split(', *')->map('v:val . \",\"')<CR>
   ```

   The expression in details:

   - `getreg('\"')` gets the content of the default register, here it is what used to be between the parentheses,
   - `split(', *')` splits it into individual arguments,
   - `map('v:val . \",\"')` appends a `,` to each item.

   NOTE: the command above makes use of the new-ish "method" notation. In older Vims, it should look like this:

   ```
   :put!=map(split(getreg('\"'), ', *'), 'v:val . \",\"')
   ```
3. Format what we just put:

   ```
   ='[
   ```

**Second**, putting it together…

Now that we have a working solution, we may want to make it a bit easier on the fingers with a simple visual mode mapping, which makes sense because it will keep it simple and agnostic:

```
xnoremap <key> c<CR><Esc><Cmd>put!=getreg('\"')->split(', *')->map('v:val . \",\"')<CR>='[
```

Which we can use like this:

```
vi(<key>
vi[<key>
vip<key>
```

etc.

NOTE: the mapping above makes use of the new-ish `<Cmd>` "special text". In older Vims, it should look like this:

```
xnoremap <key> c<CR><Esc>:<C-u>put!=map(split(getreg('\"'), ', *'), 'v:val . \",\"')<CR>='[
```

Comment: This command doesn't work for me. But it is something that I can use as a start at least. The mapped key simply does the first step and is silent. Using the step by step instruction fails on the second step with error:`E15: Invalid expression: >split(', *')->map('v:val . ","')<CR>` `E15: Invalid expression: getreg('"')->split(', *')->map('v:val . ","')<CR>`

Comment: You might have an older Vim. Try without the "method" style: `put!=map(split(getreg('\"'), ', *'), 'v:val . \",\"')`.

Comment: Yes! That seem to have been the problem. Also had to substitute "<Cmd>" with ":" but now it works. Btw, do you now how to find the documentation for map() and split(), when I search for it I only get documentation for mapping keys and splitting windows.

Comment: Nvm, found the correct documentation at last.

Comment: The first screen of `:help` explains how to form your queries for maximum efficiency: `:help map` is to broad while `:help map(` is more explicit. Same for `:help split` vs `:help split(`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement romainl answer I'll give the reverse command to be able to toggle between single line and multi-line.

Single line -> Multi line:

```
xnoremap <Key1> c<CR><Esc>:put!=map(split(getreg('\"'), ', *'), 'v:val . \",\"')<CR>='[
```

Multi-line -> Single line

```
xnoremap <Key2> :s/\%V\n\s*\(.*,\)$/\1 / <Bar> s/\%V\(.*\),\s\n/\1/ <CR>:noh<CR>
```

Usage:

```
va(<Key2>
```

Explanation:

- `:s/match/replace/flags` is search and replace which follows regular regexp matching
- `\%V` is to only search in selection
- `s/\%V\n\s*\(.*,\)$/\1/` for lines with a comma at the end move these to the preceding line and remove extra whitespace
- `<Bar>` this is a pipe
- `s/\%V\(.*\),\s\n/\1/` remove the extra last comma, space and newline

However, note that neither can handle complex cases, such as lists containing other lists.